# Textbox should not allow to TYPE numbers in input field other than 1 to 23

Tags: html

```html
<input className="form-control" style={{ width: "8rem" }} type="text" min="0" max="23" pattern="^([1-2]?[0-9]|23)$"/>
```

I tried using regex but it is allowing me add other numbers like more than 23 it should not allow numbers more than 23 input text box should allow only numbers from 1 to 23

Comment: Your regex is incorrect for your purposes. You can check your regex here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want a number input box instead of a text box. In this case you only need to use min="1" and max="23"

```html
<input classname="form-control" style="width:8rem" type="number" min="1" max="23">
```

I don't think there is a way to disallow a user from typing other values into the box, but the min and max should validate the input automatically making it a non-issue. For more information check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Validation).

On a side note, your style attribute was formatted rather oddly for some reason and didn't work on a regular webpage so I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Using a number-input (rather than text-input) and the **min** and **max** attributes is the right solution for this case, but as you mention it can also be solved with a regex pattern.

Your regex pattern would not work for this purpose, but this one would: `^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])$`

*This pattern basically says that the value must either be `1-9` or `1+0-9` (10-19) or `2+0-3` (20-23), which covers every number from 1-23.*

---

Using a regex pattern would be a good solution if you wanted to limit the value to a certain range, but also either exclude or allow additional values.

Examples:
`^([0-9]|1[1-9]|2[1-3])$`: limited to a range of **1 - 23**, but also *excludes* both **10** and **20**
`^([0-9]|1[0-9]|2([0-3]|9)|39)$`: limited to a range of **1 - 23**, but *allows* both **29** and **39**